# WCF JSONP enabled service - invalid label returned

Tags: javascript, wcf, jsonp

I have a WCF service that is returning an custom object (this works in the browser) but when I call the service from Javascript I get the invalid label error in FF. When I put the `http://localhost/Service1.svc/MethodName/param1/param2` into the browser I get the correct info back, but its looks the same as the JSON response was before I converted it to JSONP ie. I'm not sure theres a wrapper going around the response. The javascript I'm using is below:

```
function CallService() {
$.ajax({
    cache:true,
    type: varType, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
    url: varUrl, // Location of the service
    data: varData, //Data sent to server
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: varContentType, // content type sent to server
    dataType: varDataType, //Expected data format from server
    processdata: varProcessData, //True or False
    success: function (msg) {//On Successful service call
        ServiceSucceeded(msg);
    },
    error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
});

function SetupTrainList(tiploc) {
    try {
        varType = "GET";
        varUrl = "http://localhost/Service1.svc/MethodName/param1/param2";
        varContentType = "application/javascript";
        varDataType = "jsonp";
        varProcessData = false;
        CallService();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e.toString());
    }
}
```

The WCF:

```
<OperationContract()>
    <WebInvoke(BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
        Method:="GET",
        RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
        ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json,
        UriTemplate:="MethodName/{param1}/{param2}")>
    Function MethodName(ByVal param1 As String, ByVal param2 As String) As ComplexType
```

Comment: You could try [enabling WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) to look at the messages WCF is actually creating when invoked from the browser versus from JS. I'd guess the issue is caused by specifying `jsonp` to the jQuery HTTP client.

Comment: when you are trying to call the WCF REST service from jquery or javascript and the service is in a different domain you would get a cross domain access exception unless you change the dataType in your JQuery to be JSONP. In such a case you would need to provide a validation callback method for the service to write the response back to the stream and invoke the function. Find more info at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821863/use-javascript-to-connect-to-wcf-web-service/11831942#11831942